Exception log print from liblog(Android/Native)
When I print logs in a so library file integrated into Android Native, I see in logcat that part of my log is not output and is replaced by log output from liblog, why is this, is it because I print logs too high frequency?
16:32:00.141 210 1713 D wnsservice: Thread-Working(active): cur.pion
16:32:00.141   210  1713 D wnsservice: Thread-Working(active): cur.ler
16:32:00.141   210  1713 D wnsservice: Thread-Working(active): end one time calculate
16:32:00.141   210  1713 D wnsservice: Thread-Working(active): resultQueue(in)
16:32:00.151   210  1713 I liblog  : 8
16:32:00.151   210  1713 D wnsservice: Thread-Working(active): rec
16:32:00.151   210  1713 D wnsservice: Thread-Working(active): cur.veoc
16:32:00.151   210  1713 D wnsservice: Thread-Working(active): cur.pion
16:32:00.151   210  1713 D wnsservice: Thread-Working(active): end one time calculate
16:32:00.151   210  1713 D wnsservice: Thread-Working(active): resultQueue(in)
16:32:00.151   210  1713 I liblog  : 1
16:32:00.160   210  1713 D wnsservice: Thread-Working(active): datasqueue(out)
16:32:00.160   210  1713 D wnsservice: Thread-Working(active): calculate ler by data
16:32:00.160   210  1713 D wnsservice: Thread-Working(active): time gap

My module name is wnsservice , obviously there has some my log replace by the log from liblog .
I have looked for the logcat out file. I find this situation is occasional happen, it is seem that my thread is working in right status, but just has something wrong in print log.

Random guess: are you repeating the resultQueue(in) message 8 more times?

Certainly, this is an active module within the native layer of the Android system, which prints information approximately every 10 milliseconds. The log out of liblog occurs only sporadically.
